# СЕО перелинковка для Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, seo, link, package

Стоит задача, написать на Laravel 4.2 СЕО перелинковку. Среди популярных CMS обычно я использовал Htrace плагин / модуль.

**Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно его можно как-то интегрировать с Laravel, или есть уже готовые пакеты? Или писать с нуля переленковочный функционал?**

Comment: а на основе какого алгоритма вы реализовываете перелинковку?  суть в том что, на каждом фрейморке ресурс по разному реализован, и любой плагин модуль или другое творение  все равно попросит вас сказать что откуда и куда тянуть. Вам нужен алгоритм, а там уже будет все равно какой фреймворк или цмс